# Auto updating index entry page numbers

Tags: makeindex, makeidx

I am using MikTeX Version 2.9 in Windows. Currently I am using `makeidx.sty` and the `makeindex.exe` program to crate the index entries from the TeX application files by using the tag `\index`. But is it possible to update and print the page numbers of index entries without running the `makeindex` program?

Now the auto updation is fixed by using the package "`imakeidx.sty`" as suggested by TeXnician. Please suggest that how can I add the tag `\break, \pagebreak` to the particular index entry?

My MWE is follows:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[makeindex]{imakeidx}

\makeindex

\begin{document}

This is a sentence indexing the command
\index{Breaking word}
with the environment\index{abstract}
and the ordinary word `document'\index{Test document}.

\printindex

\end{document}
```

Here, I need to break the two words "Breaking word", i.e., output should generate as `\item Breaking\break word`

Please suggest...

Comment: How should that work? You run makeindex for exactly that purpose. Of course you can run it automatically, but without running you won't get updated page numbers.

Comment: Thanks, I too agree that, anyhow, I need a confirmation from some experts like you, egreg, and David Carlisle, etc :-) but please suggest me how can I run makeindex.exe by every compilation in LaTeX...

Comment: You can use the package `imakeidx` and compile with `-shell-escape`, it will run makeindex automatically (idk whether makeidx does the same to).

Comment: @TeXnician `-shell-escape` is not needed

Comment: @egreg You're right, I mixed it up with running xindy. For that it's needed.

Comment: Thanks for the great suggestion, I heard that MacTeX distribution of LaTeX, which updates/regenerates the index automatically when compiling, is this follows the same technology what you suggested?

Comment: Any updation on my request (I've modified my question), please...

Comment: You should do only minor changes to questions. If the original question changes more, a follow-up question (with link to the original one) would be better.

Answer (score 1):

I do not really understand, what you want. If you want a sub-entry use `\index{Breaking!word}`. If you really want a manual line break in an entry you may use `\index{Breaking word@Breaking\linebreak word}`.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[makeindex]{imakeidx}

\makeindex

\begin{document}

This is a sentence indexing the command
\index{Breaking word@Breaking\linebreak word}
with the environment\index{abstract}
and the ordinary word `document'\index{Test document}.

\printindex

\end{document}
```

would result in

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[makeindex]{imakeidx}

\makeindex

\begin{document}

This is a sentence indexing the command
\index{Breaking!word}
with the environment\index{abstract}
and the ordinary word `document'\index{Test document}.

\printindex

\end{document}
```

in

[image]